# Gravity in Flutter Flame

Tags: flutter, flame

I am currently following this Flutter Flame tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjGwLsjIF1o

However, even though the code works perfectly well, I can't seem to understand how the variable "_gravity" works in this code: https://github.com/Spellthorn/pixel_adventure/blob/master/lib/components/player.dart

The variable is only used once in "void _applyGravity" and I don't understand how "velocity.y += _gravity" can affect both jumping and falling and how it works ?

```
  void _applyGravity(double dt) {
    velocity.y += _gravity;
    velocity.y = velocity.y.clamp(-_jumpForce, _terminalVelocity);
    position.y += velocity.y * dt;
  }m
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`velocity` is counted in pixels/s and gravity is counted in pixels/s to be added to the velocity each tick (and defined as 9.8 here). The code from the tutorial is actually slightly wrong, because if `_gravity` is added directly to the velocity without taking `dt` into consideration, the `gravity` will be stronger if the refresh rate of the screen is higher (which means smaller `dt` and more frequent runs of `update`).

```
// Gravitational acceleration.
final _gravity = 9.8; 

// Makes it possible to avoid creating new Vector2 objects in the update loop.
final _velocityTmp = Vector2.zero(); 

@override
void update(double dt) {
  super.update(dt);
  // Apply gravity to the velocity by adjusting y-velocity based on gravity.
  velocity.y += _gravity * dt;

  // This makes sure that the velocity is within the limits defined
  // So -_jumpForce checks how much velocity upwards that is allowed
  // And _terminalVelocity is the maximum velocity downwards.
  velocity.y = velocity.y.clamp(-_jumpForce, _terminalVelocity);

  // Uses our pre-defined temporary vector2 so that we don't have to
  // create a new object in every update iteration.
  _velocityTmp
    ..setFrom(velocity)
    ..scale(dt);

  // Update position based on the current velocity.
  position.add(_velocityTmp);
}
```

Worth mentioning too is that since it is counted in pixels and not meters, you most likely want to have a higher gravitational constant than 9.8, or define a meters-to-pixels constant that you multiply all values with, but that is usually overkill for small games.